# In TensorFlow, why does the same application (same graph) have different number of operations in two different CPUs?

Tags: tensorflow

While I run the same application for CPU version in two different machines, the operations number have slight difference. The data generated from chrome tracing (TensorBoard) as follows. Theoretically, TensorFlow will generate the same graph for CPU with the same number of operations. Why do the two different CPUs have a different number of operations in the same graph for running the same application?

**Intel CPU with 14 cores (28 threads):**

4 Conv2DBackpropFilter operations spanning 30.404ms

4 Conv2DBackpropInput operations spanning 22.011ms

94 Mul operations spanning 19.997ms

108 Sum operations spanning 5.497ms

17 Mean operations spanning 2.731ms

**Intel CPU with 16 cores (32 threads):**

4 Conv2DBackpropFilter operations spanning 55.343ms

4 Conv2DBackpropInput operations spanning 47.575ms

84 Mul operations spanning 27.384ms

88 Sum operations spanning 10.075ms

12 Mean operations spanning 3.027ms

Comment: Are you talking about operations as in "tensorflow ops" or "CPU instructions"?

Comment: TensorFlow operations

Comment: Could you then post a piece of the graph.pbtxt file generated on both machines? That would be good to see exactly which nodes are there and what's going on between the two different setups